# Android Volley ServerError GET-Method

Tags: android, android-volley

I've developed a REST webservice and consume it by android client.
The webservice works fine but sometimes android volley got a com.android.volley.ServerError. If I check the url with postman everything works. This problem is just by some few users and I cannot reproduce the error.

Here is my Volley request:

```
public void requestURL(final RestCallback callback) {

    Log.d("JSON", url);

    JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    callback.onSuccess(response);

                }


            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Log.d("JSON", "onErrorResponse: " + url);
                    String errorText = null;

                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        Log.d("Error", "Timeouterror");
                        errorText = context.getString(R.string.error_timeout);
                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        Log.d("Error", "Servererror");
                        errorText = context.getString(R.string.error_server);
                    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        Log.d("Error", "Servererror");
                        errorText = context.getString(R.string.error_network);
                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        Log.d("Error", "Parseerror");
                        errorText = context.getString(R.string.error_parse);
                    }


                    Crashlytics.logException(new Throwable("Errornachricht: " + error.getMessage() + " Error: " + error.toString() + "\n URL: " + url + "\n Cause: "  +error.getCause() + " Stacktrace: " + error.getStackTrace()));
                    callback.onError(errorText);

                }
            }) {


        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            return Security.getAuth();
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            return super.getParams();
        }



    };


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);


    //sets time for retry connection
    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy( 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    jsonObjectRequest.setShouldCache(false);
    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


}
```

And the method getAuth which is called bei getHeaders:

```
public static Map<String, String> getAuth() {
    String credentials = "username" + ":" + "password";
    String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("Accept","application/json");
    headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
    headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
    return headers;
}
```

Error log:

[image]

Has anybody an idea why I got this error?

Comment: Please post your error log.

Comment: thanks. I've edited my post

Answer (score 0):

I think some times API response is not a valid JsonArray, at that time it will throw a server error. API response is a "null" or a jsonObject like wise